# i want to upload a file in laravel - php artisan command line, but i don't know how

Tags: laravel, upload, laravel-artisan

and thanks in advice for helping me
i want to upload a file in laravel - php artisan command line, but i don't know how

I'm using this code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Model\Questions;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class uploadQuestions extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'admin:uploadQuestions';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Upload questions excel file';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //TODO upload file
    }
}
```

i don't know how i can specify the file in order to upload it

Comment: What you mean with "uploading a file"? Who should be able to upload it? Why you want to do this via Artisan / Command Line?

Comment: I've done uploads from an `Artisan` command before. In a nutshell, you'd need to adjust your `$signature` to handle a file path/name, then work with that in your `handle()` function. You'd combine that with the `Storage` capabilities of Laravel and you're good to go. Have a read of https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan for more info. All that being said, this question is likely to be closed as "Too broad", as there's a lot required to achieve this.